# Avoid same table header as multiple times, when it gives as dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have an array named as groups. This array consists of name and regid. I want to display the key of name as the column header of the table. For this I used the code below:

```
   var Name=v.name; 
    var regId=v.regid;
    var rowStr = '<th data-id="'+regId+'" width="10%">'+Name+'</th>'
    $("#table tr:eq(0)").append(rowStr);
```

I except : Display name as column header, but names which has same regid must shown one time only. 
So I use :

```
    for(var i=0; i<=regId; i++) 
    {
    $("#table th").each(function()
                {
                   if($(this).data('id')== i)
                            {
                            var len=$(this).length; 
                            if(len>0)
                                {
                                    $(this).remove();
                                }
                            }

                    }); 
    }       for(var i=0; i<=regId; i++) 
    {
    $("#table th").each(function()
                {
                   if($(this).data('id')== i)
                            {
                            var len=$(this).length; 
                            if(len>0)
                                {
                                    $(this).remove();
                                }
                            }

                    }); 
    }
```

But the above code removes all header. How can it done?
Hope you can help me to solve this issue.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jm3kr12w/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below for loop instead of yours.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= regId; i++) {
    if ($("#table th[data-id=" + i + "]").length > 1) {
        $("#table th[data-id=" + i + "]:gt(0)").remove();
    }
}
```

In your code   `$(this).remove()` will remove the current header and you are looping through each header.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are seeking to append a `th`, then decide whether it was appropriate to do so and if not, remove it (and any other duplicates that may have accumulated).

If I'm correct, then it would be more efficient to make the decision and append a `th` only if applicable.

Together with some further rationalisation, I end up with this :

```
$.each(result, function(i, obj) {
    $.each(obj.data, function(j, obj2) {
        var id = obj2.id;
        if(!groups[id]) {
            groups[id] = { 'id': id, 'name': [], 'regid': [] };
        }
        groups[id].name.push(obj2.name);
        groups[id].regid.push(obj2.regid);
        var $existing = $("#table th").filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('id') == obj2.regid;
        });
        if ($existing.length == 0) {
            $('<th width="10%" />').data('id', obj2.regid).text(obj2.name).appendTo("#table tr:eq(0)");
        }
    });
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm3kr12w/33/)**